# pthread_cond_wait/signal and mutex not working as expected

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I'm trying to learn pthread/mutex, but despite a lot of research/reading on the web, i'm failing to understand what's is going wrong with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct data
{
    int Counter = 0;
    int calls = -1;
    int iteration = -1;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_cond_t condition = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
};

void* threadAlarm (void* arg);
void* threadCounter (void* arg);

int main (void)
{
    pthread_t monThreadCounter;
    pthread_t monThreadAlarm;

    struct data mydata;

    if (pthread_create (&monThreadAlarm, NULL, threadAlarm,(void*)&mydata)>0)
        printf("Pthread Alarme error\n");
    if (pthread_create (&monThreadCounter, NULL, threadCounter, (void*)&mydata)>0)
        printf("Pthread Counter error\n");

    pthread_join (monThreadCounter, NULL);
    pthread_join (monThreadAlarm, NULL);

    return 0;
}

void* threadCounter (void *arg)
{
    struct data *myarg = (struct data *)arg;
    srand(time(NULL));

    pthread_mutex_lock (&myarg->mutex);

    while(1)
    {
        myarg->Counter += rand()%10; /* We add a random number to the counter */

        if(myarg->Counter > 20) /* If Counter is greater than 20, we should trigger the alarm*/
        {
            myarg->iteration += 1; /* Iteration counter, to check any shift between expected triggers and reality */

            printf("Counter = %i(%i)-->",myarg->Counter,myarg->iteration);

            pthread_mutex_unlock (&myarg->mutex); /* Unlock mutex before sending signal */

            if (pthread_cond_signal (&myarg->condition) >0)
            {
                printf("COND SIGNAL ERROR\n");
                pthread_exit(NULL);
            }

            usleep(10000); /* The shorter the sleep is, the weirder the output is */

            pthread_mutex_lock (&myarg->mutex); /* We should get the lock again before testing/modifying any shared variable */
        }
    }
}

void* threadAlarm (void* arg)
{
    struct data *myarg = (struct data *)arg;

    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&myarg->mutex);

        //while(myarg->Counter<21) // Uneeded? Since we'll never get the lock before the Counter thread detects condition and release it
        {
            printf("\nWAITING for trigger...\n",myarg->Counter);
            if (pthread_cond_wait (&myarg->condition, &myarg->mutex)>0)
            {
                printf("ERROR COND WAIT\n");
                pthread_exit(NULL);
            }
        }

        myarg->calls+=1; // Calls counter, should be equal to iteration counter, overwise calls have been missed

        printf("ALARM TRIGGERED! Call #%i/Iteration #%i -> COUNTER RESET\n",myarg->calls, myarg->iteration);

        // Counter reset
        myarg->Counter = 0;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&myarg->mutex);
    }
}
```

This code is supposed to have a thread incrementing a counter by a random value until it becomes greater than 20, what will then trigger a condition for another waiting thread that should display a message and reset the counter. And so on.

What i don't understand, is that despite i think i'm using mutex and pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_signal as described in various examples from the web, it does not behaves as expected if i don't introduce a usleep to slow it down.

With the `usleep(10000)`, i got the expected output:

```
WAITING for trigger...
Counter = 23(59)-->ALARM TRIGGERED! Call #59/Iteration #59 -> COUNTER RESET

WAITING for trigger...
Counter = 23(60)-->ALARM TRIGGERED! Call #60/Iteration #60 -> COUNTER RESET

WAITING for trigger...
Counter = 21(61)-->ALARM TRIGGERED! Call #61/Iteration #61 -> COUNTER RESET
```

Call/Iteration counters are in sync, prooving that every time the condition is reached, the "alarm" thread is correctly triggered.

But, if i reduce the sleep, the result becomes to get weird. With no sleep at all (commented out), i get for example:

```
WAITING for trigger...
Counter = 21(57916)-->Counter = 23(57917)-->Counter = 29(57918)-->Counter = 38(57919)-->Counter = 45(57920)-->Counter = 45(57921)-->Counter = 45(57922)-->Counter = 49(57923)-->Counter = 52(57924)-->Counter = 55(57925)-->Counter = 61(57926)-->Counter = 65(57927)-->Counter = 70(57928)-->Counter = 77(57929)-->Counter = 83(57930)-->Counter = 86(57931)-->Counter = 92(57932)-->Counter = 95(57933)-->Counter = 99(57934)-->Counter = 107(57935)-->ALARM TRIGGERED! Call #4665/Iteration #57935 -> COUNTER RESET

WAITING for trigger...
Counter = 24(57936)-->Counter = 28(57937)-->Counter = 31(57938)-->Counter = 31(57939)-->Counter = 36(57940)-->Counter = 41(57941)-->Counter = 45(57942)-->Counter = 47(57943)-->Counter = 54(57944)-->Counter = 54(57945)-->Counter = 56(57946)-->Counter = 62(57947)-->Counter = 64(57948)-->Counter = 66(57949)-->Counter = 66
```

...

Despite the counter has reached the triggering state, it doesn't seems to trigger the alarm thread and continues to increase, and calls/iterations counters are completely out of sync, prooving that numerous calls have been missed.

How can i ensure that every time i issue a pthread_cond_signal the waiting thread is really triggered and the calling thread will wait until the mutex is released by the triggered thread?

In case it matters, i'm currently coding on Linux Ubuntu.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You cannot put an initializer into the definition of the struct. How did you even get this to compile?

Comment: What's the value returned from `pthread_mutex_lock()`, `pthread_mutex_unlock()`, and pthread_cond_signal()`?

Comment: Looks like that code is rather C++ than C, could that be the case? Make sure you keep those two languages apart! In C++, you would also not use POSIX threads usually but their own threads. That said, upon waking up after waiting on a condition variable, you have to check for the actual condition! Als, you need to do that before even going to sleep! These are common mistakes, which probably come from the name "condition variable", which is a bit misleading.

Comment: >Andrew Henle: mutex locks and unlocks always return 0 (no error)

Comment: >Ulrich Eckhardt: You're right, it's a C++ project. Could you please elaborate on why i should keep those two languages apart?

Comment: @GeraldB. *mutex locks and unlocks always return 0 (no error)* [Oh, do they now?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781944/pthread-mutex-lock-returns-invalid-argument)  Please read the **RETURN VALUE** and **ERRORS** sections:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_mutex_lock.html

Comment: @Andrew Henle: I'm not sure to understand your comment. After reading your first comment, i've added a check of the value returned by each lock/unlock, and even before any other modification (with my first non working version code), i had no other returned value than 0. So my problem was not because of a non working lock/unlock.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour.  Once you signal the condition variable, the waiting thread will eventually wake up and contend for the mutex, but there's no guarantee that the signalling thread won't be able to re-acquire the mutex before that happens.

If you want the counter thread to wait for the alarm to be consumed, you need to actually program it to do that.  You can use the same condition variable the other way around - in the counter thread:

```
if (pthread_cond_signal (&myarg->condition) >0)
{
    printf("COND SIGNAL ERROR\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

pthread_mutex_lock (&myarg->mutex); /* We should get the lock again before testing/modifying any shared variable */

/* Wait for alarm to happen */
while (myarg->calls < myarg->iteration)
{
    pthread_cond_wait(&myarg->condition, &myarg->mutex);
}
```

and in the Alarm thread, call `pthread_cond_signal(&myarg->condition)` at some point after incrementing `myarg->calls`.

---

By the way, you *do* need the `while(myarg->Counter<21)` that you have commented out in the alarm thread.  Consider these two scenarios:

1. The alarm thread is blocked at `pthread_mutex_lock()` at the beginning of its main loop.  The counter thread has the mutex and has just incremented `myarg->Counter` to a value greater than 20.  It unlocks the mutex and signals the condition variable, *before* the alarm thread gets a chance to run.  The alarm thread then runs, acquires the mutex and blocks in `pthread_cond_wait()` - it will wait here forever, because we've now made sure that the counter thread will wait for the alarm to be consumed before continuing.
2. The alarm thread has just decremented the counter to zero, unlocked the mutex, immediately re-locked it at the top of the loop and called `pthread_cond_wait()`.  `pthread_cond_wait()` returns immediately (due to a "spurious wakeup", which is allowed) before the counter thread got a chance to acquire the mutex, and the alarm thread will now continue even though the counter is still zero.

Comment: Adding a "reverse" condition/wait between the 2 threads solves the "missed calls" problem, but it sometimes happens to hold into the alarm thread. Uncommenting the `while(myarg->Counter<21)`solve that second problem, and everything now seems to work perfectly well. I have to say that none of the examples i've read across the web were showing a correct use of wait/signal. My example was inspired by [a lesson from openclassrooms.com](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/la-programmation-systeme-en-c-sous-unix/les-threads-3) (in french) which is then obviously wrong!

Answer (score 0):

This is the working version, in case it could be useful to somebody else:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>


struct data
{
    int Counter = 0;
    int calls = -1;
    int iteration = -1;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_cond_t condition = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
};

void* threadAlarm (void* arg);
void* threadCounter (void* arg);

int main (void)
{
    pthread_t monThreadCounter;
    pthread_t monThreadAlarm;

    struct data mydata;

    if (pthread_create (&monThreadAlarm, NULL, threadAlarm, (void*)&mydata)>0)
        printf("Pthread Alarme error\n");
    if (pthread_create (&monThreadCounter, NULL, threadCounter, (void*)&mydata)>0)
        printf("Pthread Counter error\n");

    pthread_join (monThreadCounter, NULL);
    pthread_join (monThreadAlarm, NULL);

    return 0;
}

void* threadCounter (void *arg)
{
    struct data *myarg = (struct data *)arg;
    srand(time(NULL));

    if (pthread_mutex_lock(&myarg->mutex) > 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR Mutex lock1 Counter\n");
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

    while(1)
    {
        myarg->Counter += rand()%10; /* We add a random number to the counter */

        if(myarg->Counter > 20) /* If Counter is greater than 20, we should trigger the alarm*/
        {
            myarg->iteration += 1; /* Iteration counter, to check any shift between expected triggers and reality */

            printf("Counter = %i(%i)-->",myarg->Counter,myarg->iteration);

            if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&myarg->mutex) > 0) /* Unlock mutex before sending signal */
                {
                    printf("ERROR Mutex Unlock Counter\n");
                    pthread_exit(NULL);
                }

            if (pthread_cond_signal (&myarg->condition) >0)
            {
                printf("COND SIGNAL ERROR\n");
                pthread_exit(NULL);
            }

            if (pthread_mutex_lock(&myarg->mutex) > 0) /* We should get the lock again before testing/modifying any shared variable */
                {
                    printf("ERROR Mutex lock2 Counter\n");
                    pthread_exit(NULL);
                }

            /* Wait for alarm to happen */
            while (myarg->calls < myarg->iteration)
            {
                pthread_cond_wait(&myarg->condition, &myarg->mutex);
            }
        }
    }
}

void* threadAlarm (void* arg)
{
    struct data *myarg = (struct data *)arg;

    while(1)
    {
        if (pthread_mutex_lock(&myarg->mutex) > 0)
            {
                printf("ERROR Mutex lock Alarm\n");
                pthread_exit(NULL);
            }

        while(myarg->Counter<21)
        {
            printf("\nWAITING for trigger...\n");
            if (pthread_cond_wait (&myarg->condition, &myarg->mutex)>0)
            {
                printf("ERROR COND WAIT\n");
                pthread_exit(NULL);
            }
        }

        myarg->calls+=1; // Calls counter, should be equal to iteration counter, overwise calls have been missed

        printf("ALARM TRIGGERED! Call #%i/Iteration #%i -> COUNTER RESET\n",myarg->calls, myarg->iteration);

        // Counter reset
        myarg->Counter = 0;

        if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&myarg->mutex) > 0)
            {
                printf("ERROR Mutex Unlock Alarm\n");
                pthread_exit(NULL);
            }


        if (pthread_cond_signal (&myarg->condition) >0) //Signal back to Counter thread
        {
            printf("COND SIGNAL ERROR\n");
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

    }
}
```